# Why does my PhoneGap location function return the position multiple times?

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap

I have this function that is supposed to get higher accuracy GPS results:

```
navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition = function (geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, geoprogress, options) {
    var lastCheckedPosition,
        locationEventCount = 0,
        watchID,
        timerID;

    options = options || {};

    var checkLocation = function (position) {
        lastCheckedPosition = position;
        locationEventCount = locationEventCount + 1;
        // We ignore the first event unless it's the only one received because some devices seem to send a cached
        // location even when maxaimumAge is set to zero
        if ((position.coords.accuracy <= options.desiredAccuracy) && (locationEventCount > 1)) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            foundPosition(position);
        } else {
            geoprogress(position);
        }
    };

    var stopTrying = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        foundPosition(lastCheckedPosition);
    };

    var onError = function (error) {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        geolocationError(error);
    };

    var foundPosition = function (position) {
        geolocationSuccess(position);
    };

    if (!options.maxWait)            options.maxWait = 10000; // Default 10 seconds
    if (!options.desiredAccuracy)    options.desiredAccuracy = 20; // Default 20 meters
    if (!options.timeout)            options.timeout = options.maxWait; // Default to maxWait

    options.maximumAge = 0; // Force current locations only
    options.enableHighAccuracy = true; // Force high accuracy (otherwise, why are you using this function?)

    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(checkLocation, onError, options);
    timerID = setTimeout(stopTrying, options.maxWait); // Set a timeout that will abandon the location loop
};
```

Which I then call with:

```
navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, onProgress, {desiredAccuracy:20, maxWait:15000});
```

When it finds a position, it will fire `geolocationSuccess(position);` (the success from the above function. The problem is that in my PhoneGap application, it seems to be calling it multiple times often. Sometimes 4-5 times within the same second.

Why would that be? I am only initializing it once and it's not in any loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the script answers your question on the [github readme](https://github.com/gwilson/getAccurateCurrentPosition) (emphasis is mine):

> A better way to do this is to use navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(). This method will do a callback every time the location changes or every time the device improves the accuracy (based on my observations). In my own testing with a freshly booted device, it will take between 2 and 6 callbacks to get to something highly accurate.  This led me to write this very simple JavaScript function **that uses watchPosition()** in combination with a simple timer.

So the author is using the `geolocation watchPosition()` method in this implementation.
The callback from the `watchPosition()` method might get called several times if the position or the accuracy changes. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Watching_the_current_position)  (emphasis is mine again):

> If the position data changes (either by device movement or if more
>   accurate geo information arrives), you can set up a callback function
>   that is called with that updated position information. This is done
>   using the watchPosition() function, which has the same input
>   parameters as getCurrentPosition(). **The callback function is called
>   multiple times**, allowing the browser to either update your location as
>   you move, or provide a more accurate location as different techniques
>   are used to geolocate you. The error callback function, which is
>   optional just as it is for getCurrentPosition(), can be called
>   repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me fix the problem. I ended up setting a variable after successfully receiving a position, which then prevented the code from running again.